# for looping through rows of a tibble runs properly but produces values for i

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to write a for loop in R that produces a number range based a value in col 3 and checks if the value in col 2 falls within that range. For positive hits I would like it print out the entire row

I think my current for loop is running properly (no positive results) but it produces weird values in my workspace

here is my current for loop:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    low <- (df[[i, 3]] - 11)
    high <- (df[[i, 3]] + 11)

    if(df[[i, 2]] < high && df[[i, 2]] > low) {
    print(df[[i,]])
   }
}
```

a simplified data frame of the data looks like this

```
df = data.frame(Gene = c("ABCA7", "AP1B1", "CENPE", "COPA", "COPA", "COPA", "ZNF592"), 
     Starting.Position = c(273, 188, 1541, 1207, 1207, 545, 1052), 
     Mutation = c(1293, 230, 2562, 792,792,792, 186))
```

When I run this loop nothing is outputted--which i think is accurate---but three objects are created in my workspace: "high = 197, low = 175, and i = 6L". Not sure why this is happening and it is bothering me, would like to know why and I am unable to find any errors in my code. These values are the loop running on the last row of the data frame.

Thank you, I am relatively new to using R.

Comment: R doesn't create a new scope for `for()` statements. Any variables used for iteration or that are created inside the for block will still exist after the for block. You could instead create proper function that you can call to limit variable scope.

Comment: So there is nothing wrong with the code itself but it is not best practice I should be creating a function and then apply over the data frame instead? Can you elaborate on what limiting variable scope entails

Comment: Well, i'm not sure if it's "best practice" to write a function in this case, but that would eliminate the problem of variables lingering after you are done with them. But what is this look even supposed to be doing? Are you trying to subset your data.frame? Or are you really just printing a subset of values to the screen? You could likely do this without any explicit looping at all (which is how things are "usually" done in R).

Comment: The actual data frame is a couple hundred rows long and I wanted to identify the rows where the mutation value is relevant e.g. close to the starting position. So i guess i am just printing a subset  to the screen. Maybe i took a convoluted solution to an easy problem. How would you have gone about it, if i may ask?

Comment: Probably something like `subset(df, Starting.Position < Mutation+11 & Starting.Position > Mutation-11)`

Comment: Lol wow, brillant. Can't believe i didn't think of that. How do i give you a check mark

Answer (score 0):

As @MrFlick says, it is because you are creating those variables within your code. When you run your code, it produces an output that is stored in the workspace (i.e. memory) but nothing is output into the terminal as the outcome of the code is an empty value.

The variables are created here:

```
low <- (df[[i, 3]] - 11)
high <- (df[[i, 3]] + 11)
```

Comment: okay that makes sense, so this is not really an issue then? I am still confused on why a value of i is created though. This is the first time i've run a for loop, do they always produce a value of i that is supposed to be ignored/deleted?

Comment: It needs to create a variable `i` so that it has one to work on - basically you need to supply the variables for R to work with, otherwise it can't do anything - at least that's my very amateur non-CS understanding of it.